# Is my understanding of discontinuity correct?

Tags: calculus, functions, definition, continuity

I'd like to define three things and ask if my understanding is correct / if there is anything I am wrong about or missing.

1. A removable discontinuity exists at $x=a$ when $\lim_{x \to a-} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a+} f(x) = L$ for real $L$, but $f(a) \neq L$. And $f(a)$ may or may not be defined.
2. A jump discontinuity exists at $x=a$ when $\lim_{x \to a-} f(x) = L_1$ and $\lim_{x \to a+} f(x) = L_2$ where $L_1, L_2$ are both real and $L_1 \neq L_2$. And $f(a)$ may or may not be defined.
3. An essential/infinite discontinuity exists at $x=a$ when both the left and right limit exist at $a$ and at least one of them tends to $\pm \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change 3 to say "when at least one of them is $\pm\infty$, or doesn't exist". For instance, $f(x)=\sin\frac1x$ has an essential discontinuity at $x=0$.

Comment: I'm unclear what it means for a left/right-handed limit to not exist? I'm only familiar with two-sided limits not existing if both limits don't equal each other.

Comment: To "not be equal to each other", they need to exist! Otherwise, what would you be comparing?

Comment: I understand, but what's an example of a one-sided limit that doesn't exist where the other side does?

Comment: @user525966 Have f(x) to be $sin \frac {1}{x} $ at $0< x$ and x=0 otherwise.